# Sometimes jQuery plugin is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery a lot, but sometimes I get stuck because my browser cannot see the jQuery library, or maybe loads the library after running the my JavaScript code.

Pseudo-code to explain my question:

```
<html>
    <head>
        I always load CSS here
        I always load jquery here
    </head>
    <body>
      <p class="link-style3"><span id="my_tag"><span>Bize Hemen Yazın</span></span></p>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $('#my_tag').click(function(e) { 
            alert('tesrt');
          });
        });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I always put my stuff in the order like below, but this doesn't work now. When I click the `<span id="my_tag">`, it doesn't do anything, and doesn't return any error.

what should I do?

Here is the entire code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddkF5/)

Comment: Where is the reference for the jQuery library?

Comment: Have you included the `jQuery` library there?

Comment: can you post some real code that produces this problem? it should work fine based on what you've provided so there must be something else going on

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery library correctly? And putting it before your <script> tag?

Comment: jquery is included in the header

Comment: If it was included in the header, was it loaded correctly? Check with developer tools to ensure that the file can be found.

Comment: I put the entire code in http://jsfiddle.net/ddkF5/

Comment: No typo? script tag is close? Because else we cant really know what's happening..

Comment: The fiddle does not (it cannot) link you css and js files though. Are your JS files in the same directory as that of the page? Because that's the only thing that can be erroneous

Comment: they are all in the same folder. and I checked the links and they are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid some syntax errors like(suggestable only)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#my_tag').click(function() { 
        alert('tesrt');
     });
  })
</script>
```

and put your code at the top after you load the js files

Comment: I'd argue that a better advice would be to move the JS file references to the bottom of the page, instead of mashing all of them up there in `<head>`.

Comment: yes it will be better idea but after page loads may it consider the first priority and I mentioned that AFTER THE LOAD OF JS FILES may help...but i suggested only

Comment: in html5 the `type` is not more necessary

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can do:

- inspect your document (network pane in devtools) to see if everything
  is loading correctly
- Move your scripts to the bottom of the page
- use $(document).ready(function(){ ... });

Comment: OP already posted code and its looking bottom of page just before closing of body tag and $(document).ready(function(){ ... }) is same as $(function(){ ... })

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya true. I guess he should use the no-conflict method instead: 

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });

But frankly, I'm guessing it has more to do with loading issues.